# Checking the entered 3-letter word in 25x25 randomly generated table

Tags: c#

`Capital letters consisting of random Turkish characters will be assigned to a 25 x 25 table array. If there is a 3-letter entry (TEA, JOY, EGG, etc.) table followed by the keyboard, create a program that shows these letters in different colors.
Note: If there is an input string entered from the keyboard, different ornament representation will be made by a method. Coding with c#.

```
    char[,] table = new char[25, 25];
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            tablo[i, j] = (char)('A' + random.Next(0, 29)); // Türkçe büyük harfler için 'A' ile 'Z' arasındaki harfler kullanılır 
        }
    }

    // Tablo dizisinin ekrana yazdırılması 
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(tablo[i, j] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Klavyeden kelime girişi alınması 
    Console.Write("Kelime girin: ");
    string kelime = Console.ReadLine();

    // Kelimenin tablo dizisinde aranması ve farklı renkte gösterilmesi 
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            if (i <= 23 && j <= 23)
            {
                string kontrolKelime = "" + tablo[i, j] + tablo[i, j + 1] + tablo[i, j + 2]; // 3 harfli kelime kontrolü 
                if (kelime == kontrolKelime)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; // Farklı renk ayarı 
                    Console.Write(kelime + " ");
                    Console.ResetColor(); // Renk sıfırlama 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(tablo[i, j] + " ");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(table[i, j] + " ");
            }
       }
```

``where is my problem`